# UILocalNotification ScheduledNotification Empty After Kill Application

Tags: ios, iphone

i am working on Alarm clock application, When i Schedule one or more alarm and after create alarm i kill application, after that i start application again now if i schedule one more alarm than old Scheduled alarm notification array `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]` is empty and new one is inserted in this array. So my old Scheduled notification never called.
And i am create multiple alarm at a time so i am not able to store notification in user default.